# First-Order Taylor Expansion of Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

If $f:\Omega \subset \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, I want to show that $f(z+h) = f(x+iy) + \partial_x f \cdot h_1 + \partial_y f \cdot h_2 + o(|h|) $. I am not sure why the third term on the right should be $\partial_y f \cdot h_2$ rather than multiplied by $i$, that is, $\partial_y f \cdot h_2 i$.

My professor said this is because of the real differentiability of $f$, implied by its complex differentiability, but I'm not sure how this answers my above doubt.

Comment: think of $f$ as a pair of real differentiable functions on the plane (or a real differentiable function from the plane to the plane) and how you express real differentiability for such; for example if $f=u+iv$ then $f=(u,v)$ and $u(x,y)=u(x_0, y_0)+ (x-x_0)u_x(x_0, y_0)+(y-y_0)u_y(x_0, y_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$ and similarly for $v$ while $u_x+iv_x=f_x, u_y+iv_y=f_y$ so when you add the approximations for $f=u+iv$ you get the above

Comment: @Conrad That solved my problem. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why it should be $\partial_y f \cdot h_2$ is explained the way your professor said.

By thinking of $f$ as a function $R^2 \to R^2$, so $z = (x,y)$, then the above is just the Taylor expansion for a totally differentiable function $R^2 \to R^2$.

Note: I am assuming that $h=(h_1,h_2)$, so $z+h = (x,y) + (h_1, h_2) = (x,y) + (h_1, 0) + (0, h_2)$, and $f = u + iv$, so $f = (u,v)$ for $u, v : R \to R$.

Specifically, letting $Df(x,y)$ denote the total derivative at $(x,y)$, then $Df(x,y)(h) = Df(x,y)(h_1,  0) + Df(x,y)(0,h_2) $
$= h_1 \cdot Df(x,y)(1,0) + h_2 Df(x,y)(0,1) = h_1 \cdot \partial_x f (x,y) + h_2 \cdot \partial_y f (x,y) $
$= h_1 \cdot (\partial_x u (x,y), \partial_x v (x,y) ) + h_2 \cdot (\partial_y u (x,y) ,\partial_y v (x,y))$.

So the more interesting question is why not $i \partial_y f \cdot h_2$?

Basically the idea is that the partial derivative in the y direction is "already the $i$ direction", so multiplying that result by $i$ would rotate by a further 90 degrees, $h_2 \cdot (\partial_y v (x,y), -\partial_y u (x,y) )$, which is not what you really want.

**EDIT:** Given complex numbers (considered as elements of $R^2$) $z = (z_1, z_2)$ and $w = (w_1, w_2)$, complex multiplication can be represented as matrix multiplication:

$$ w z = (w_1, w_2) \cdot_{\mathbb{C}} (z_1, z_2) := \begin{bmatrix} w_1 & - w_2 \\ w_2 & w_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

in other words, by identifying the vector $(w_1, w_2)$ with the $ 2 \times 2$ matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} w_1 & - w_2 \\ w_2 & w_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

In the relationship mentioned in the comment $$f(z+h) = f(z) + a(h_1 + i h_2) + o(|h|) $$
the complex scalar $a$ is the Jacobian of $f$, i.e. the complex derivative $f'(z)$

$$a (h_1+ i h_2) = f'(z) (h_1 + ih_2) = \begin{bmatrix} (f'(z))_1 & - (f'(z))_2 \\ (f'(z))_2 & (f'(z))_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{bmatrix} = Df(x,y)\begin{bmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_x f(x,y) & \partial_y f(x,y) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_x u(x,y) & \partial_y u(x,y) \\ \partial_x v(x,y) & \partial_y v(x,y) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

Notice that the above implies the Cauchy Riemann equations, $\partial_x u(x,y) = \partial_y v(x,y)$, $\partial_y u(x,y) = - \partial_x v(x,y)$. I.e. the Cauchy Riemann equations just express the requirement that the Jacobian of the function be a linear function that represents multiplication by a complex scalar.

Comment: I get that, if we see $f$ as a function $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$, your analysis works to get the above. But then, seeing it as a function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, I am still not sure how to rigorously show that the above is what we expect: my notion of complex differentiability only yields $f(z + h) = f(z) + a(h_1 + ih_2) + o(|h|)$, rather than the condition with the partials. Your last paragraph sketches intuition for this, but still doesn't show it rigorously.

Comment: @algebroo Maybe the edit addresses your concern? Possibly not the lack of rigor though